# for loop read html challenge in R

Tags: r, loops, parsing, for-loop

I would like to loop a parse query. 
The thing that stops me is that I need to insert a number in the html that R then reads and parses. The html should be between " ", does anyone know how to insert the "i" from the "for loop" so that it will be replaced and R is also able to retrieve the html?

This is the code (I would like a list with all the artists of the charts of the 52 weeks):

```
 library(rvest)

    weeknummer = 1:52

    l <- c()
    b <- c()
    for (i in weeknummer){
    htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.top40.nl/top40/2015/week-"[i]"")
    Top40html <- html_nodes(htmlpage,".credit")
    top40week1 <- html_text(Top40html)



            b <-  top40week1
            l <- c(l,b)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the URL into one string.

```
pageurl <- paste0("http://www.top40.nl/top40/2015/week-",i)
 htmlpage <- read_html(pageurl)
```